# Como paralelizar a função do.call

Tags: r

Estou precisando fazer uma montagem de múltiplos `rasters` para um único `raster`. Tanto a função `raster::merge` quanto `raster::mosaic` funcionam bem nessa situação, porém preciso fazer um `do.call` para chamar a função para a montagem dos multiplos `rasters` que estão em uma lista.
 Como fazer isso paralelizado? Como fazer o do.call mais rápido?

```
require(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
r1 <- crop(r, extent(-10, 11, -10, 11))
r1[] <- 1:ncell(r1)
r2 <- crop(r, extent(0, 20, 0, 20))
r2[] <- 1:ncell(r2)
r3 <- crop(r, extent(9, 30, 9, 30))
r3[] <- 1:ncell(r3)
rast.list <- list(r1, r2, r3)     
rast.list$fun <- mean
rast.mosaic <- do.call(mosaic,rast.list)
```

Comment: tente colocar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível do que você está fazendo. Da forma como a sua pergunta está, será difícil obter uma boa resposta

Comment: -1 até apresentar um exemplo reprodutível.

Comment: @FlavioBarros , o exemplo parece reprodutível

Answer (score 0):

Para paralelizar uma função, você pode usar o pacote `purrr`.

A função `map2` serve para usar vários argumentos numa função de uma só vez:

```
library(tidyverse)
a = c("Eu sou o Igor.", "Eu sou o João.")
b = c(" Eu gosto disso.", " Eu gosto daquilo.")

map2(a, b, ~stringr::str_c(.x, .y))
#[[1]]
#[1] "Eu sou o Igor. Eu gosto disso"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Eu sou o João. Eu gosto daquilo"
```

Veja só o que está acontecendo. O valor `a` está sendo aplicado como primeiro argumento na função `str_c`. O valor `b` está sendo aplicado como segundo argumento.

Você pode usar `map2_chr` para retornar um vetor de caracteres:

```
map2(a, b, ~stringr::str_c(.x, .y))
#[1] "Eu sou o Igor. Eu gosto disso"   "Eu sou o João. Eu gosto daquilo"
```